# How can I recreate default arguments in C++ like in Python?

Tags: python, c++

I have this class in Python that I am trying to recreate in C++,

```
class Node:
    
    def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next= next
```

So far I have constructed this in C++,
`.h`

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node* next;
        
        Node(int value, Node next) : value(0), next(NULL){
            std::cout << "inside .h" << "\n";
        };
};
```

and `.cpp`

```
Node::Node(int value, Node next) {
    this->value = value;
    this->next = &next;   
}
```

The code itself confuses me, it is usually best practice to avoid writing methods inside the `.h` but it wouldn't let me set the default values without `{...}`, i.e. I could not type `Node(int value, Node next) : value(0), next(NULL);` which I initially expected. It seems that I have defined two constructors aswell, which seems odd given the same parameters.

inside `main` it is not allowing me to instantiate an object as `Node(5)` etc...

Do we have a new way in C++ to mimic the Python class above?

Comment: Those aren't default values. Those are field initializers. You're completely ignoring the arguments.

Comment: I think you mean "how can I recreate *default arguments* in C++"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the same way, by providing [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

```
Node(int val = 0, Node* nxt = nullptr) : value(val), next(nxt) {}
```

This is both the default constructor, and the one that takes an `int` and a pointer to `Node`.

---

#### As a sidenote:

You may want to have the following form instead, adds flexibility:

```
Node(Node* nxt = nullptr, int val = 0) : next(nxt), value(val) {}
```

This way you can create *(connect)* a `Node` with default value:

```
Node n(&next_node); // a Node instance with default value 0
```

Comment: I am having a look at the link you provided but I can't seem to find where they talk about default arguments using the `example(type x, type y): x(...), y(...)`

Comment: @Joe changed the link to a more appropriate one. Check the first paragraph.

Comment: oh, I see this is what the first comment meant, those are field initializers...